# How to click on the first <li> automatically when I come to the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this html block of code:

```html
<div class="row" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
     <ul id="portfolio-flters">
        <li data-filter=".filter-journal">Journal articles</li>
        <li data-filter=".filter-wp">Working papers</li>
        <li data-filter=".filter-conferences">Conferences</li>              
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this javascript function that clicks on `<li>` :

```js
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let portfolioContainer = select('.portfolio-container');
    if (portfolioContainer) {
      let portfolioIsotope = new Isotope(portfolioContainer, {
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
      });

      let portfolioFilters = select('#portfolio-flters li', true);

      on('click', '#portfolio-flters li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        portfolioFilters.forEach(function(el) {
          el.classList.remove('filter-active');
        });
        this.classList.add('filter-active');

        portfolioIsotope.arrange({
          filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
        });
        portfolioIsotope.on('arrangeComplete', function() {
          AOS.refresh()
        });
      }, true);
    }

  });
```

The page looks like this now:

[image]

But I would like to click on the first

that is `<li data-filter=".filter-journal">Journal articles</li>` automatically when I come to the web page. I tried to add a `click()` method of the first portfolioFilters element to simulate a click event on the first li element when the page loads, but it doesnt change anything:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let portfolioContainer = select('.portfolio-container');
    if (portfolioContainer) {
        let portfolioIsotope = new Isotope(portfolioContainer, {
            itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
        });

        let portfolioFilters = select('#portfolio-flters li', true);
        // Click on the first li element
        portfolioFilters[0].click();

        on('click', '#portfolio-flters li', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            portfolioFilters.forEach(function(el) {
                el.classList.remove('filter-active');
            });
            this.classList.add('filter-active');

            portfolioIsotope.arrange({
                filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
            });
            portfolioIsotope.on('arrangeComplete', function() {
                AOS.refresh()
            });
        }, true);
    }
  });
```

Desired output is:

[image]

How can I do this please?

Comment: Try moving the clicking code to after `on("click", ...)`.

Comment: Are you asking how to click on an element, or how to highlight it based on the current page URL? Why do you want to click on it, won't that trigger an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clicking the element before attaching the `click` listener. This should work if you reorder your code like this:

```
on('click', '#portfolio-flters li', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    portfolioFilters.forEach(function(el) {
        el.classList.remove('filter-active');
    });
    this.classList.add('filter-active');

    portfolioIsotope.arrange({
        filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
    });
    portfolioIsotope.on('arrangeComplete', function() {
        AOS.refresh()
    });
}, true);

let portfolioFilters = select('#portfolio-flters li', true);
// Click on the first li element
portfolioFilters[0].click();
```